# Replacing Cornstarch with Flour in Potato Pancakes Recipe

Tags: substitutions, cornstarch

I have followed [this](https://jasmineandtea.com/korean-cheese-potato-pancakes/) recipe for Korean cheese potato pancakes a few times, and the results come out as expected. I don't have a lot of corn starch on hand and would like to make a larger serving of the pancakes. Is it possible to replace the corn starch (partially or fully) with flour? Would this effect the crispiness of the pancakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on personal experience with other Korean pancakes, you can replace the cornstarch with flour, but at the cost of making the pancakes less crispy and more chewy.

If you have tapioca starch, potato starch, or even rice flour, that would work somewhat better.